# Android studio Getsharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, xml, save

I have wandering around forums and seen plenty of users looking for a way to use sharedpreferences in a textfield and save it permanently and not having to use a "call" button. I am one of thosse users hehe.. Right now i have a username field where i can click on a button "save" to save the data but when i restart the app the data from the userfield (textfield) is gone and i have to use another button to "call" the data back to the field. How do i change the code so when you click save the data you just wrote in stays there when you restart the app.
My code for retrieving the data looks like this. The "for123" is the onclick for the call button.

```
}
//Hämta nummer knappen
    public void for123(View view){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String name = sharedPref.getString("username", "");
        numTxt.setText(name + " ");

}
```

this is almost the whole mainActivityjava file, didn't know how to import the start of the java file hehe..

```
Button sendSMS;
Button sendSMSaon;
Button sendSMSaoff;
Button sendSMSrela1;
Button sendSMSrela2;
EditText msgTxt;
EditText numTxt;
EditText aonTxt;
EditText aoffTxt;
EditText rela1txt;
EditText rela2txt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skicka);
    sendSMSaon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skickaaon);
    sendSMSaoff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skickaaoff);
    sendSMSrela1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skickarela1);
    sendSMSrela2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skickarela2);

    msgTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Textmeddelande);
    numTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nummer);
   aonTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aon);
    aoffTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aoff);
    rela1txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rela1txt);
    rela2txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.relä2txt);

    msgTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    aonTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    aoffTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rela1txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rela2txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    sendSMSaoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           String mymsgaoff = aoffTxt.getText().toString();
                                           String theNumber = numTxt.getText().toString();
                                           sendMsg(theNumber, mymsgaoff);
                                       }

                                   }

    );

    sendSMSaon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          String mymsgaon = aonTxt.getText().toString();
                                          String theNumber = numTxt.getText().toString();
                                          sendMsg(theNumber, mymsgaon);
                                      }

                                  }







    );
    sendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       String myMsg = msgTxt.getText().toString();
                                       String theNumber = numTxt.getText().toString();
                                       sendMsg(theNumber, myMsg);
                                   }

                               }
    );
    sendSMSrela1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       String myMsgrela1 = rela1txt.getText().toString();
                                       String theNumber = numTxt.getText().toString();
                                       sendMsg(theNumber, myMsgrela1);
                                   }

                               }
    );
    sendSMSrela2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          String mymsgrela2 = rela2txt.getText().toString();
                                          String theNumber = numTxt.getText().toString();
                                          sendMsg(theNumber, mymsgrela2);
                                      }

                                  }







    );


}

//Sparar numret

public void saveInfo(View view) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("username", numTxt.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();

    Toast.makeText(this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}
//Hämta nummer knappen
    public void for123(View view){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String name = sharedPref.getString("username", "");
        numTxt.setText(name + " ");

}
private void sendMsg(String theNumber, String myMsg)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(theNumber, null, myMsg, null, null);



}
```

}

Comment: give me your complete class code,

Comment: Thank you for code, looking at your code i cant see any place where you are calling this methods. They should be called on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best suggestion would be to use your function in the `onResume` lifecycle method. That way it will be called anytime your application comes into focus.

It works like this:

```
public void for123(View view){
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  String name = sharedPref.getString("username", "");
  numTxt.setText(name + " ");
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  for123(/* Whatever view you are in*/);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Really apreciated it! I will try it out now! I'm developing it for a company who needs a basic app so I am doing my best at it. So if i just figure at the most basic stuff it will be fine

Comment: No problem! I'm in your same shoes! I'm new to iOS and Android development, but the best way to learn is by doing! (And with a lot of help from Stack Overflow ;) )

Comment: I tried the codes! It worked!!! Whohooo! The project can continue! you made everything possible with that lines of codes! Incredible! :D :D Thank you guys.

Comment: Awesome! Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

To save shared preference data,

```
public callStopButtonClick(){

 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

editor.putString("username", "<value of username>")
editor.commit();

}
```

write your code on on resume,

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String name = sharedPref.getString("username", "");
        numTxt.setText(name + " ");

    }
```

I am not sure this will help you or not, but i hope this will give you way to achieve your goal.